# Pandas get ranking of column names with NA

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, ranking

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'val1': [1, np.NaN, 2, 3], 
                         'val2': [np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, np.NaN], 
                         'val3': [3, np.NaN, 1, 1]},
                   index=pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], name='index'))
>>> df1
       val1  val2  val3
index
1       1.0   NaN   3.0
2       NaN   1.0   NaN
3       2.0   NaN   1.0
4       3.0   NaN   1.0
```

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63343695/9871643), I have created a dataframe with column names as values:

```
i = np.argsort(df1.to_numpy(), axis=1)
r = pd.DataFrame(df1.columns.to_numpy()[i],
                    index=df1.index,
                    columns=range(1, i.shape[1] + 1)).add_prefix('Rank')
>>> r
      Rank1 Rank2 Rank3
index
1      val1  val3  val2
2      val2  val1  val3
3      val3  val1  val2
4      val3  val1  val2
```

However, I am trying to leave the out the `NA` values from the ranking like so:

```
>>> r
      Rank1 Rank2 Rank3
index
1      val1  val3  NaN
2      val2  NaN   NaN
3      val3  val1  NaN
4      val3  val1  NaN
```

I believe `argsort` method does not have any parameters to skip the Null values. I've tried converting the missing values to (-1) like the following, but I can only do it for a series and not a dataframe:

```
>>> series = df1.iloc[0]
>>> series.argsort()
val1    0
val2   -1
val3    1
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi! I added an answer handling NaNs to the question you make reference to in the link. I will add the answer here too, in case it is considered a new question given the NaN particularity.

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a function which allows you to create the ranking treating null cases correctly:

- It allows including NaN values and avoids using those columns for the rank columns (leaving their values as NaN too). Check the example.
- It also adds the corresponding rank values to map them easily.
- Has an additional parameter in case you want to rank them in ascending or descending order.
- Adds an additional column specifying which columns had NaN values and were not included in the rank columns. Those values are added in a list. Useful in the event that you later want to analyze these cases.

```
# Example DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dic = {'A': [0, np.nan, 2, np.nan],
      'B': [3, 0, 1, 5],
      'C': [1, 2, 0, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(df)

     A  B    C
0  0.0  3  1.0
1  NaN  0  2.0
2  2.0  1  0.0
3  NaN  5  NaN
```

```
# Function
def fun_rank_columns(df, ascending=False):
    factor = 1 if ascending else -1
    # Rank columns showing ranking of column names
    np_sort = np.argsort(df.to_numpy() * factor, axis=1)
    df_rank = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.columns)[np_sort], index=df.index, columns=range(1, np_sort.shape[1] + 1))
    
    # Corresponding values for each rank column
    np_sort_value = np.sort(df.to_numpy() * factor, axis=1)
    df_rank_value = pd.DataFrame(np_sort_value, index=df.index, columns=range(1, np_sort_value.shape[1] + 1)) * factor
    
    # Columns with nan values to be replaced
    num_col_rank = df_rank.shape[1]
    df_rank['nan_value'] = df.apply(lambda row: [i for i in df.columns if np.isnan(row[i])], axis=1)
    for col in range(1, num_col_rank + 1):
        condition = df_rank.apply(lambda x: x[col] in x['nan_value'], axis=1)
        df_rank.loc[condition, col] = np.nan
        df_rank_value.loc[condition, col] = np.nan

    # Join Results
    df_rank = df_rank.add_prefix('rank_')
    df_rank_value = df_rank_value.add_prefix('rank_value_')
    df_res = df_rank.join(df_rank_value)
    return df_res
```

```
# Apply the function
df_res = fun_rank_columns(df, ascending=True)
print(df_res)

  rank_1 rank_2 rank_3 rank_nan_value  rank_value_1  rank_value_2  rank_value_3
0      A      C      B             []           0.0           1.0           3.0
1      B      C    NaN            [A]           0.0           2.0           NaN
2      C      B      A             []           0.0           1.0           2.0
3      B    NaN    NaN         [A, C]           5.0           NaN           NaN
```